I am facing issues after updating jekyll to version 4.3.3
I had jekyll working fine before updating my rubygems. After updating jekyll and some rubygems, I encounter exceptions being raised on my cmd.
After jekyll updated to v4.3.3, I had issues running even the simplest of the commands, such as jekyll -v, bundle exec jekyll s. The issue raised was the same on all executions.
I received the following error:
C:\Users\frankdexdevs\Documents\kails>bundle exec jekyll s
C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/lib/addressable/idna/pure.rb:163:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/data/unicode.data (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/lib/addressable/idna/pure.rb:163:in `open'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/lib/addressable/idna/pure.rb:163:in `<module:IDNA>'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/lib/addressable/idna/pure.rb:21:in `<module:Addressable>'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/lib/addressable/idna/pure.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/lib/addressable/idna.rb:25:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/lib/addressable/idna.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/lib/addressable/uri.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll.rb:33:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `<main>'
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- idn (LoadError)
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/lib/addressable/idna/native.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/lib/addressable/idna.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/addressable-2.8.6/lib/addressable/uri.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll.rb:33:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/frankdexdevs/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/exe/jekyll:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `<main>'

I expected my jekyll serve to run as it did before upgrading jekyll. I tried to uninstall jekyll and install it again as most recommended but this did not work. Wondering what the issue might be.

Try to revert to the previously working version.

I tried but since I have so many projects, I need a way to handle this. It indeed will mess me a bunch if I had to revert.

It seems Ruby is loading gems from your local gem installation, and not from the bundle. Did you try bundle install to see if there are missing gems?

I did this too many a times but it doesn't work. I wonder what the issue is.

Is there an error message when you run bundle install? Or do you mean it does not help? Try uninstalling the addressable gem gem uninstall addressable. Then run bundle install again, or run gem install addressable to reinstall.

I noticed I have addressable-2.8.4 and addressable-2.8.6. I looked inside and found that the v2.8.4 had a data directory not available in v2.8.6. I copied the folder data to the latter and yeah, it works again. I don't know why it misses the data directory and also unsure of the steps to take. @Casper, should I use your commands above to sort the issue?

Nah. You have better things to do now. Great that you got it working. We do not know the reason for the failure right now. Might be failed installation of the addressable gem, a bug, nobody knows. If you have a lot of spare time, you can try my suggestions (which may lead to more problems) otherwise I suggest you not touch it for now.

Do not touch it if it works. I hope this will help anyone who gets this kind of issue. Thanks a lot.
